# OpenXML Add paragraph style (Heading1,Heading2, Head 3 Etc) to a word processing document

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, word-automation

Can anybody guide me how to add predefined styles on paragraph using open XML Word Processing? I have tried various solutions available on forums but nothing works for me. Here is what i want to accomplish:

```
// Create a document by supplying the filepath. 
WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create("E:/Test/Executive.Docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

// Add a main document part. 
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

// Create the document structure and add some text.
mainPart.Document = new Document();
Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
   
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text("Executive Summary"));
if (para.Elements<ParagraphProperties>().Count() == 0)
    para.PrependChild<ParagraphProperties>(new ParagraphProperties());

// Get the ParagraphProperties element of the paragraph.
ParagraphProperties pPr = para.Elements<ParagraphProperties>().First();

// Set the value of ParagraphStyleId to "Heading3".
pPr.ParagraphStyleId = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading1" };
```

Answer (score 16):

Your technique would totally work if you were editing an existing document. The problem is that a fresh document doesn't have a "Heading 1" predefined.  You'd have to add it. So you have two choices:

**1. Work with an existing template document**

Create a template document (TemplatePath) to use as a base. In the code, copy it to the final destination (FinalPath) and add text/whatever to it, applying styles.  Heading 1 will already be in the template.

```
if (File.Exists(FinalPath))
  File.Delete(FinalPath);
File.Copy(TemplatePath, FinalPath);
WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(FinalPath, true);
Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text("Executive Summary"));
para.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties(new ParagraphStyleId() { Val="Heading1" });
```

**2. Create your new document from scratch**

If you do this, it will have no built-in styles. So create a style, call it "Heading 1" and apply it to your paragraph.

```
WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(FinalPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
mainPart.Document = new Document();
Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text("Executive Summary"));
StyleDefinitionPart styleDefinitionsPart = wordDocument.AddStylesDefinitionPart();
Styles styles = styleDefinitionsPart.Styles;
Style style = new Style() {
  Type = StyleValues.Paragraph, 
  StyleId = styleid, 
  CustomStyle = true
};
StyleName styleName1 = new StyleName() { Val = "Heading1" };
style.Append(styleName1);
StyleRunProperties styleRunProperties1 = new StyleRunProperties();
styleRunProperties1.Append(new Bold);
styleRunProperties1.Append(new Italic());
styleRunProperties1.Append(new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Lucida Console" };);
styleRunProperties1.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "24" });  // Sizes are in half-points. Oy!
style.Append(styleRunProperties1);
styles.Append(style);
pPr.ParagraphStyleId = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "Heading1" };
para.PrependChild<ParagraphProperties>(new ParagraphProperties());
```

<sarcasm>See? OpenXML is a piece of cake!</sarcasm>  I swear, my eyes are rolling so hard I'm getting a headache.

Comment: StyleDefinitionPart should be StyleDefinitionsPart

Comment: what is styleid? pPr is also not initialized. This is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the style names depends on your Microsoft Office language, e.g.:

**Heading 1**

```
in English is: "Heading 1"
in Hungarien is: "Címsor 1"  -> style id: "Cmsor1"
```

By looking in your Word document xml style file you will be able to find above information.

**Steps:**

1. Rename any word document, e.g. "sample.docx" to "sample.zip"
2. Open the "sample.zip".
3. Open "word" folder in the zip file.
4. Open "style.xml" file.
5. Search the style name or properties of what you are looking for.

The style hierarchy is very important.